# IMDB Award Data

Tags: data-request

I was looking for award data (oscars? golden globes?) on this site: ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/pub/misc/movies/database/frozendata/

I saw this https://www.imdb.com/event/ev0000292/1963/1/?ref_=ev_eh and thought "oh the ftp site may have an "event" one but there isn't one listed. Can anyone assist?